# CRUD de usuarios, agregar mas rutas de edit y update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, crud

Actualmente tengo un CRUD para los usuarios. Estoy utilizando la ruta de edit y update para modificar los datos de nombre y correo, pero requiero otra ruta de edit y otra de update para cambiar la contraseña del usuario. Quiero trabajarlos de manera separada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La duda es como generar esas nuevas rutas de edit2 y update2. Intente agregarlas al controlador de usuario y no las creo.

Coloco el código del controlador de usuario en el que agregue la funcion de edit2 para crear la ruta pero no funciona:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\UserStoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UserUpdateRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;



class UserController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $users = User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate();

    return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
     return view('admin.users.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(UserStoreRequest $request)
{
    //validacion
    $user = User::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('users.edit', $user->id)
        ->with('info', 'Usuario creado con exito');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    return view('admin.users.show', compact('user'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    return view('admin.users.edit', compact('user'));
}

public function edit2($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    return view('admin.users.edit2', compact('user'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    $user->name     = $request->name;
    $user->email     = $request->email;

    $user->save();  

    return redirect()->route('users.index')
                     ->with('info','El usuario ha sido actualizado');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id)->delete();

    return back()->with('info', 'Eliminado correctamente');
}
}
```

Tambien coloco el codigo de rutas web

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('inicio');
});

Route::get('instituto', function () {
return view('instituto');
})->name('instituto');



Route::redirect('news', 'blog');

Auth::routes();

//Web
Route::get('blog', 'Web\PageController@blog')->name('blog');
Route::get('entrada/{slug}',   'Web\PageController@post')->name('post');
Route::get('categoria/{slug}', 'Web\PageController@category')->name('category');
Route::get('etiqueta/{slug}',  'Web\PageController@tag')->name('tag');
//Admin
Route::resource('tags',       'Admin\TagController');
Route::resource('categories', 'Admin\CategoryController');
Route::resource('posts',      'Admin\PostController');
Route::resource('users',      'Admin\UserController');
```

**EDIT1:**  Agregue las rutas y me las reconoce el route:list

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero sigo obteniendo el mensaje de que no reconoce la ruta, tambien fueron agregadas al controlador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo, intentas generar un nuevo método para **edit** y otro para **update**, con sus correspondientes rutas.

Para empezar, deberemos definir estas rutas nuevas. Como ya tenemos las rutas del resource, deberemos definir **antes** de ella las rutas que queremos añadir, de la siguiente manera:

```
Route::get('users/{user}/edit2', 'Admin\UserController@edit2');
Route::put('users/{user}/update2', 'Admin\UserController@update2');
Route::resource('users', 'Admin\UserController');
```

De esta forma tenemos las rutas del **resource** ([Documentación de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers)), y dos nuevas rutas que puedes llamar como más te convenga. A continuación definimos los métodos en el controlador:

```
public function edit2($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    return view('admin.users.edit2', compact('user'));
}

public function update2(UserUpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    // Actualizamos

    $user->save();  

    return redirect()->route('users.index')
                     ->with('info','El usuario ha sido actualizado');
}
```

Si ya tenemos las vistas y los enlaces/formularios llaman correctamente a las rutas debería funcionar todo correctamente. Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

**EDIT 1:**

Acabo de ver tu edición, tu problema puede que sea por que estás llamando desde la vista **index.blade.php** a una ruta definida con el nombre `users.edit2`. Como puedes ver en tu captura del `route:list` todas tienen nombre salvo las dos que acabamos de definir, para agregarle un nombre debes dejarlas de la siguiente manera:

```
Route::get('users/{user}/edit2', 'Admin\UserController@edit2')->name('users.edit2');
Route::put('users/{user}/update2', 'Admin\UserController@update2')->name('users.update2');
Route::resource('users', 'Admin\UserController');
```

Coméntame que si tienes algún problema de esta forma.

Comment: ¿y como sería en la vista?, ¿asi? {!!Form::model($id,['method'=>'PATCH','route'=>['users.update2',$id->id],'files'=>'true'])!!} {{Form::token()}}